# Qt creator doesn't see right CMake version

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am trying to compile C++ project in Qt creator using CMake, but get a message:

> error: CMake 3.1 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.0.2

In terminal `cmake --version` gives 3.7.0, `which cmake` gives /usr/local/bin/cmake. In Qt creator I go

Tools>Options>CMake

but the version under /usr/local/bin/cmake is auto-detected and set as default. And of course the project won't compile if I just manually lower the required version (I tried).

I don't get what else can be wrong. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: make sure the newer version of CMake is at the front of your `PATH` environment variable. [QtCreator uses PATH](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html) to find CMake.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, `echo $PATH` said /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib

Comment: The way you phrased your question makes it seem like that's the problem. What does `/usr/local/bin/cmake --version` return?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, `/usr/local/bin/cmake --version`
cmake version 3.7.0

Comment: and I'm assuming you opened QtCreator from that same terminal? E.g. you don't have a bashrc vs. bash_profile kind of issue?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, I usually open Qt creator from GUI and now I couldn't figure out the command which executes it from terminal (I'm novice)

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, but I could paste contents of both files if it helps

Comment: go for it. All we can really tell you right now is that you have a path problem, that you have 2+ cmake versions installed, and Qt is getting the wrong one.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, maybe I should just purge Cmake and reinstall it?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, I think I'll try to delete one of them and upgrade the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NicolasHolthaus I realized i just had two working versions of CMake installed on my machine. I deleted both, then reinstalled one and now everything works.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: How did you delete both?.. I tried `sudo apt-get purge cmake` but somehow managed to keep the annoying one..

Answer (score 1):

Please check the output in the "General Messages" output pane at the bottom of the window (you might need to enable that with the small button on the right next to the list of panes).

Creator will show what it runs there. Is it indeed using the expected cmake? If not: Change it in Tools>Options>Build & Run>Kits.

Comment: This should've been a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @ray: Sorry, I rarely come here and am not too well-versed in the finer details of stack overflow. I'll try to do the right thing next time.

Comment: No worries. In general, if you need clarification, or have questions (need OP's output of something to proceed), a comment is more appropriate..